# Progress bar in kivy can't update using loop

Tags: kivy

im traying to do a progress bar in kivy, i can build the app with it but it can't be udpated when i run a function (loop) how can i do this please ?

here is my code : 
import libraries :

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
```

My builder :

```
Builder.load_string("""
<RootWidget>:
    pb : pb
    some code here
        ActionView:       
            ActionPrevious:
                with_previous: False 
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Run analysis'
                    color: 29/255, 185/255, 84/255, 1
                    on_release: root.clicked()
    BoxLayout:
        ProgressBar:
            id : pb
            min :0
            max :1
            pos_hint: {'x': .1}
            size_hint_x :.8
            size_hint_y :.5
            value: 0
        """)
```

other code with my update_bar function:

```
class Myapp(BoxLayout):

    pb = ProgressBar()
    box = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Myapp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def update_bar(self,dt=None):
         self.ids.pb.value = self.ids.pb.value
```

here is the problem : the progress bar is not updated each iteration, but it take the last value (for i = 9999)

```
     def clicked(self):
        for i in range(10000) :
            self.ids.pb.value =  i/10000 
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_bar,0.5)
            self.update_bar()
```

Build my app :

```
class EventScreen(App,Myapp):
    def on_stop(self):
        Logger.critical("Good bye")
    def build(self):
        return Myapp()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    EventScreen().run()
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Clock.create_trigger()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#triggered-events) to update progress bar.

## Snippet

```
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Myapp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.update_bar_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.update_bar)

 def clicked(self):
    self.i = 0
    self.update_bar_trigger()

def update_bar(self, dt):
    if self.i <= 10000:
        self.ids.pb.value += self.i
        self.i += 1
        self.update_bar_trigger()
```

Comment: Thank you @Ikolim for your help, that work fine, but it takes a lot of time to finish my program. In your function "update_bar", i must manipulate some big dictionaries and lists, so this way is too slow for me. is there a fast solution for the progress bar please ? thank you

Comment: Hello again, finally it is fast now by adding -1 in Clock.create_trigger(self.update_bar,-1)  to call my update_bar function before the next frame. Many thanks for you solution :)